# SpeechKit SDK (Dragon Mobile) - Crash on Initialization

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

We have a repeating crash when initilizing Speechkit.
It only happens sometimes on both iOS7 & iOS8 and we could not identify a specific scenario.

We were using ver. 1.0.3 and upgraded to 1.4.12. This issue happens in both versions.

The trace looks like:

```
 EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000
 Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
 0  CoreFoundation                 0x25521ca4 CFArrayGetCount + 23
 1  24me                           0x00548de1 -[TAGPValue(Hash) hash]
 2  24me                           0x00548de1 -[TAGPValue(Hash) hash]
 3  24me                           0x00548bf3 -[TAGPValue(Hash) hash]
 4  24me                           0x00548513 -[TAGPValue(Hash) hash]
 5  24me                           0x0054b6a9 -[TAGPValue(Hash) hash]
 6  24me                           0x0038ab17 -[ViewController   setupTextToSpeechInterface] (ViewController.m:1370)
 7  24me                           0x0037a481 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] (ViewController.m:196)
```

//this is the method we use to initialise

```
  -(void)setupTextToSpeechInterface{

        if (![SpeechKit sessionID]) {
              [SpeechKit setupWithID:@"XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                      host:@"ti.nmdp.nuancemobility.net"
                      port:443
                    useSSL:NO
                  delegate:nil];
         }
```

}

Comment: I’ve not used this before but I note the contradiction of arguments. port assigned is 443 (SSL) but the useSSL argument says NO. So maybe adjust the port or the SSL argument?

Comment: Did you fixed this crash?

Comment: @Matan Did you fixed the crash?